# Deploying Spring Boot application in tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot

The picture below shows the actual log in screen when i run the application in eclipse.

[Application when executed with eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFGP.png)

I've package the application in war using maven install. When i deployed the war package in tomcat, the application doesn't seem to show the actual template as shown above but instead like this.

[Application when deployed in tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fWPb.png)

Please help and thank you in advance.

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.Ridzuan</groupId>
<artifactId>TCFBRoster</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>TCFBRoster</name>
<description>Roster for TCFB</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>TCFB</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my header.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head th:fragment="common-header">

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>
<title>TCFB</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Website Font style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
...
```

Here are my directories

Roster > WEB-INF > classes > templates > common > header.html

Roster > WEB-INF > classes > static > css > ...

Comment: On a first glance, your CSS are not getting loaded. How are you referring to the CSS files, is it a relative URL? or getting directly from 3rd party hosted domains?

Comment: BTW, a valuable advice which is not directly related to this question. If possible do not deploy it to conventional tomcat.. use embedded tomcat instead, it will save you lot of troubles.

Comment: Rename the *.war file to with *.zip extension. Unzip the file and verify if it has the css files. If it has, then maybe the path was not set correctly.

Comment: I would encourage you to use google chrome's developer tools or firebug etc to analyze the network calls and see what URL your header.html hits to load the css files